# Processing multiple conditio in an IF Statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

I am trying to write a conditional statement that will check to see if session.play_type is not true and that a session.sku is not present.

Example of what I'm trying to do.
`If, { condition: session.play_type != 'm_only' && session.sku != 2101-10 || 2101-31 || 2101-12 || 2101-21 || 2101-20 }`

```
React.createElement(
    If,
    { condition: session.play_type != 'm_only'},
    React.createElement(
        If,
        { condition: session.showDown == true },
        React.createElement(
            If,
            { condition: session.s3_down != '' },
            React.createElement(
                'a',
                { className: 'btn btn-dark btn-popover', href: "javascript:sendGoogle('" + session.event + "','" + removeApos(session.title) + "','" + session.sku + "','" + session.s3_down + "');", 'data-toggle': 'popover', 'data-trigger': 'focus', title: 'Download', 'data-content': '' },
                React.createElement('i', { className: 'fa fa-download' })
            )
        )
    )
),
```

Comment: Is that real code?

Comment: @jarmod yes its real react jsx code ... I am trying to add a condition to check session .sku's